preauthorizeBasic/preauthorizeApiKey in swagger using python flask
I need to implement preauthorizeApiKey/preauthorizeBasic using python flask , but I don't find any documentation stating that . Tried searching online as well but seems like swagger is mostly done with Java and .NET , there are not solution available for python
